# Unreachable code after switch statement

Tags: android, eclipse

```
public Cursor query(Uri paramUri, String[] paramArrayOfString1, String paramString1,String[] paramArrayOfString2, String paramString2)
  {             
SQLiteQueryBuilder localSQLiteQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    if (paramUri.getPathSegments().size() == 1);
     for (StringBuilder localStringBuilder = null; ; localStringBuilder = new   StringBuilder(100))
      switch (sURIMatcher.match(paramUri))
      {
    case 0:

    case 1:

    case 2:

    case 3:
     default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + paramUri); 
      }
    localSQLiteQueryBuilder.setTables("category");//unreachable code


    while (true)
    {
      Cursor localCursor = localSQLiteQueryBuilder.query(mOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(), paramArrayOfString1, paramString1, paramArrayOfString2, null, null, paramString2);
      localCursor.setNotificationUri(contentResolver, paramUri);
      return localCursor;
      localSQLiteQueryBuilder.setTables("shop,category");
      localSQLiteQueryBuilder.appendWhere("shop_category_id=category._id");
      continue;
      localSQLiteQueryBuilder.setTables("shop,category");
      StringBuilder localStringBuilder;
  localStringBuilder.append("shop_category_id=category._id");
      localStringBuilder.append(" AND ");
      localStringBuilder.append("_id");
      localStringBuilder.append('=');
      localStringBuilder.append((String)paramUri.getPathSegments().get(1));
      localSQLiteQueryBuilder.appendWhere(localStringBuilder.toString());
      continue;
     localSQLiteQueryBuilder.setTables("shop,category");
     localSQLiteQueryBuilder.setDistinct(true);
     localStringBuilder.append("shop_category_id=category._id");
     localStringBuilder.append(" AND ");
     localStringBuilder.append("shop_category_id");
     localStringBuilder.append('=');
     localStringBuilder.append((String)paramUri.getPathSegments().get(1));
     localSQLiteQueryBuilder.appendWhere(localStringBuilder.toString());
     paramString2 = "shop._id";
}
}
```

I get unreachable code error after switch statement and I can't figure it out how to solve it.I tried to delete that line but if I do I get a lot of errors.My code is above.Can anyone help me?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The code is really unreachable:

All the cases are fall-through (they have no `break` statement, so all cases after a match will execute) and end in the `default` case which throws an `Exception`. This means the code after throwing the `Exception` will never be executed.

Perhaps what you meant to do was rahter sth like this:

```
 switch (sURIMatcher.match(paramUri)){
    case 0:
      // do something
      break;
    case 1:
      // do something
      break;
    case 2:
      // do something
      break;
    case 3:
      // do something
      break;
    default:
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + paramUri); 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies.I made the changes ,but I'm still having this problem.

Comment: @melib - that's strange. Could you please add your new code as an edit to your question - only the first unreachable line and the lines above it - everything that comes after the first unreachable line is irrelevant.

Comment: Hey,thanks a lot for your interest,but I solved the problem.I had a semicolon after  if (paramUri.getPathSegments().size() == 1) and this caused the error.I deleted it and now everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is due to your bad switch...you must use `break;`

```
switch (sURIMatcher.match(paramUri))
  {
case 0:
      //your code
      break;
case 1:
      //your code
      break;
case 2:
       //your code
      break;
case 3:
      //your code
      break;
default:
     //your code
     break;      
 }
```